# Is it possible to normalize "double-dots" URL using nginx?

Tags: nginx, rewrite, curl, url

According to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2) URL like this

```
http://example.com/catalog/category/goods/../brand/product.html
```

converted by some UserAgent (curl would be nice example) to  `http://example.com/catalog/category/brand/product.html`

How can I achieve such  behavior using nginx rewrite, if my stupid UserAgent can not parse original URL in correct way?

Is it ever possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `/./` sequences and `/goods/../` sequences with a single `/`. For example:

```
rewrite ^(.*)/\./(.*)$ $1/$2 redirect;
rewrite ^(.*)/(?!\.\.)[^/]+/\.\./(.*)$ $1/$2 redirect;
```

The `/(?!\.\.)[^/]+/` sequence should match any path element that is not another `..`. The above rewrites are recursive and issue 302 responses until all of the `/./` and `/../` sequences are correctly removed.

Alternatively, the same can be achieved using an internal redirect, by placing `rewrite...last` statements within a suitable `location` block. For example:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)/\./(.*)$ $1/$2 last;
    rewrite ^(.*)/(?!\.\.)[^/]+/\.\./(.*)$ $1/$2 last;
}
```

In this case, the URL displayed on the browser's address bar will not be changed.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details of the `rewrite` directive, and [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for details of the negative lookahead assertion.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to use the first rules given by you.
I'm familiar enough with simple nginx rewrite rules, but tight stockage of slashes and dots makes me stuck and a little bit sick

Answer (score 3):

As I see nginx normailses URL by default. Quoting [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

> a normalized URI, after decoding the text encoded in the “%XX” form,
> resolving references to relative path components “.” and “..”, and
> possible compression of two or more adjacent slashes into a single
> slash.

I've tested and it works out of box here (with proxy_pass), or do you have any problems with that?

Comment: At that time, it was a problem with nginx configuration for 1C Bitrix CMS or bug in software for SEO analysis, as far as I remember. The problem becomes obsolete for nowdays.